# What's causing my Svelte each block to not display array data fetched using Axios and Sveltekit?

Tags: axios, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I am completely new to coding, so I might encounter some difficulties in comprehending the explanation. However, I'm in dire need of assistance!

Here are the specific details of my situation:

[Api-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBvGg.png)
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gHYh.png)

Svelte.js and API Integration: I am utilizing the Svelte.js framework to build my application, and I have integrated an API to fetch the required data. The API is expected to provide the data in a suitable format for rendering.

Fetching and Parsing the Data: I have successfully implemented the logic to fetch the data from the API endpoint. Upon receiving the response, I have also ensured that the data is properly parsed into a suitable JavaScript object or array format.

Storing Fetched Data: In order to facilitate the rendering process, I have created an array variable within my Svelte component to store the fetched data. This array acts as a container to hold the relevant information.

Troubles with Rendering: Despite having the fetched data stored in the array, I am currently facing difficulties when attempting to display it on the screen. My initial approach involved using an [#each] block, which is commonly utilized in Svelte.js for iterating over arrays or iterable objects and rendering corresponding templates for each item.

Expected Outcome: I am expecting the data from the array to be rendered and displayed on the screen as desired. However, currently, no data is being shown, leading me to believe that there might be an issue with my implementation or approach.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code as (formatted) text, not image. See [ask].

Comment: Having difficulty understanding your question; however are you using asynchronous rendering of your each block using {#await} https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks - will show each after fetching your data or perhaps {#key} [https://svelte.dev/tutorial/key-blocks], will remount child each block every time array variable changes.